# retrieve Comma separated values in MySQL php with LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
        )
)
```

above array is an `$id`

```
$grp_id="";
foreach($id as $gid)
{
   $grp_id .=  " LIKE %".$gid['id']."% AND rj.applyto";
}
```

my query is

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `table` j INNER JOIN `table2` rj ON j.eid = rj.eid WHERE rj.applyto LIKE $grp_id";
```

i did an mistake in my auery pls suggest me to coorect..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need to use `LIKE` here? `1` and `2` are so common I don't think it is what you want.

Assuming that is not what you really want, just use `IN()`. Much simpler.

```
// Create comma separated list of IDs
$ids = implode(',', $id);
// Use IN() in our WHERE clause
$sql="SELECT * FROM `table` j INNER JOIN `table2` rj ON j.eid = rj.eid WHERE rj.applyto IN($ids);
```

Comment: hi applyto(21,26,24,25) in my table, example my id is 26 , your id is 21 both id's will run

Comment: This will do that for you.

Comment: bro john applyto(16,21) if id is 21 it will not working but 16 it will working

Comment: That should work. If it doesn't you should check your database to make sure you have the values you are expecting in there. Also run the query from the command line to see what results you get.

Comment: hm, my problem is an array , any idea to sort the above array i given

Comment: when you use where in

so if comapnyid = 1 :

companyID IN ('1,2,3')

this is return true

but if the number 1 is not in the first place

 companyID IN ('2,3,1')

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implode your ids with comma separated and use FIND_IN_SET for this like:

```
$ids = implode(',', $id_array);
$sql="SELECT * FROM `table` j INNER JOIN `table2` rj ON j.eid = rj.eid WHERE FIND_IN_SET(rj.applyto, $ids)";
```

Try this!